# MySQL Select into variable not working always

Tags: mysql

I am facing a strange behavior.

SELECT INTO and SET Both works for some variables and not for others. Event syntaxes are the same.

```
SET @Invoice_UserId :=  (SELECT UserId FROM invoice WHERE InvoiceId = @Invoice_Id  LIMIT 1); -- Working
SET @myamount := (SELECT amount FROM invoice WHERE InvoiceId = @Invoice_Id LIMIT 1); - Not working
SELECT  Amount INTO @myamount FROM invoice WHERE InvoiceId = 29  LIMIT 1; - Not working
```

If I run these queries directly then works, but not working in the stored procedure.

Comment: what you are expecting and what is the output you are getting

Comment: It should return the value in the Amount field instead it is returning 0 or null

Answer (score 1):

All of the syntaxes are valid and will work (apart from the invalid comment `-` which should be `--`.

If you have a problem, please post the full stored procedure.

In the stored procedure you should use local variables (`DECLARE var`) instead of user defined variables (`@var`) as local variables are strongly typed and have scope of the routine.

Comment: Comments are added only here those are not in SP

It is working now, problem was that SP Parameter Name Amount was same as table columns name, so instead selecting it from column it was setting the parameter value to variable.

thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you would have shown the actual stored procedure, we would have known that. It is always best to show the actual code that gives you problem, not just an excerpt of it.